# Using xmodmap to remap Caps_Lock to Control and Tab to Alt breaks C-M-KEY combos

Tags: x11, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, keyboard-layout, xmodmap

Here's the goal: swap <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> and <kbd>CtrlL</kbd> and also swap <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>AltL</kbd>.  (This would allow me to have both useful modifiers easily accessible).

I have tried a few different ways to do this with `xmodmap` but keep running into the same problem: I can swap the two keys such that all <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>KEY</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>KEY</kbd> combinations work separately but **some** key combinations with both <kbd>Alt</kbd> *and* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> fail to work.  Specifically, after the remapping `C-M-q` (that is, `Control + Alt + q`), `C-M-w`, `C-M-a`, `C-M-s`, `C-M-z`, and `C-M-x` no longer work (even though they worked before the remapping).  All other `C-M-KEY` combinations appear to work.

Here's the script I ran most recently to remap the keys (pretty much straight from the final example in the man page:

```
remove Lock = Caps_Lock
remove Control = Control_L
keysym Control_L = Caps_Lock
keysym Caps_Lock = Control_L
add Lock = Caps_Lock
add Control = Control_L

remove Mod1 = Alt_L
keysym Tab = Alt_L
keysym Alt_L = Tab
add Mod1 = Alt_L
```

I previously achieved the same remapping by directly assigning keycodes taken from `xev` for the respective keys but ran into the exact same issue.  A copy of the output of `xmodmap -pke` is available at this gist: https://gist.github.com/codesections/61d46e4abfb6116e38cb35b3c34ad72d

I've banged my head against this for quite a while without getting anywhere and would greatly appreciate any help anyone can provide!

Comment: The problem is a the deeper level -- I've tested with a program reading directly from `/dev/input/event0` -- depressing any of the QWASZX keys while Tab and CapsLock are down will not produce any event and will block the whole keyboard until the Tab and CapsLock are released.

Comment: That was on an AT keyboard. On a USB keyboard it will not block it, but depressing QWASZX while Tab and CapsLock are down will still not produce any event besides the repeating Tab and CapsLock.

Comment: @mosvy thanks!  I've confirmed that was my issue—the key combination was impossible to press at a hardware level.  Since my question was about how to use xmodmap correctly, I'd be happy to accept that as a solution if you want to re-post it as one (it doesn't get me the outcome I want, but does answer the question about how to use xmodmap)